# Python regex: sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex / python code:

```
REGISTRY_REGEX = re.compile("((HKEY(?:_\w+)+|HK[CLU][RUMC])\\([a-zA-Z\d\/\\.{}\s-]+))")
```

which should match this string:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aRandomServiceName
```

When I run my python script, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regex_id.py", line 11, in <module>
    REGISTRY_REGEX = re.compile("((HKEY(?:_\w+)+|HK[CLU][RUMC])\\([a-zA-Z\d\/\\.{}\s-]+)))")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

This regex seems to work in RegExr, what am I missing?

Comment: The regex in the question and in the stack trace are different. The one in the stack trace has additional `)` at the end.

Comment: I've tried adding `r` before your pattern this way: `re.compile(r"((HKEY(?:_\w+)+|HK[CLU][RUMC])\\([a-zA-Z\d\/\\.{}\s-]+)))")` and there error message was gone

Comment: I have no idea how that happened... I know I copied it over. And thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the expression in your question and the expression in your traceback are different. The former has two closing parenthesis, the latter has three.

The second problem is that both have too many closing parenthesis. Because you are using double quotes, all of your backslashes are getting substituted *before* being compiled by re.

The solution is to use a raw string so that your backslashes don't get substituted twice:

```
REGISTRY_REGEX = re.compile(r"((HKEY(?:_\w+)+|HK[CLU][RUMC])\\([a-zA-Z\d\/\\.{}\s-]+))")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace the `re` library with the `regex` library to fix this problem.

Comment: It would be much better if you provide more supporting information to your answer.